# Device database access

Tags: android, adb

I am running my android application in android device, and I want to see the **Database** of my application on device, how can I do this?

I know the way how can we do this in emulator but i want to know the way how can we do this in android device.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: My mobile is in working condition...
I just don't know the way how we can do this...

Comment: Ok, do you wish to access the Sqlite database?

Comment: ya, I want to access SQLite DB on my android device.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to access it manually or programmatically?
If manually, you can look into using adb or a terminal/file explorer on the device.

```
adb pull path_to_sqlite_db
```

would get it onto your computer where you can inspect it however you want.